# Making a new column out of specific lines from within a file?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am trying to solve the following problem but several attempts have failed to get it right.

Supposing I have the following in a file:

```
a,b,c

d,e,f

g

h
```

I need some way to add g and h as a third column so that the file looks like this:

```
a, b, c, g

d, e, f, h
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Are you indexing from zero? Your output puts g and h in what would normally be called column 4. What code have you tried? Your problem description needs more details. Do files always have exactly four lines, two with 3 columns and two with 1 column?

Answer (score 1):

if data in 'd' file, tried on gnu awk:

```
awk -F, '$0~/\S/ {if(NF>1) {m[++i]=$0} else {n[++j]=$0}} END{for(;c++<i;){print m[c]","n[c]}}' d
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that I understand your question to be about how to join line 3 to the end of line 1, and line 4 to the end of 2, and then line 7 to the end of 5, and 8 to the end of 6, and so on.

I assume that you really have an input file like:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g
h
```

If your file really is double spaced like that you could fix it using:

```
sed '/./!d' FILE
```

Then to join every second line to the line 2 lines before it:

```
cat FILE | sed '/./!d' | awk '
  BEGIN {
    d[0] = ""; d[1] = ""
  }
  {
    n = NR % 2
    if (d[n] == "")
      d[n] = $0
    else {
      print d[n] "," $0
      d[n] = ""
    }
  }
  '
```

I'm happy to further explain this code if you ask.

Also, if you need to handle the possibility that the file contains an odd number of lines, like

```
a,b,c 
d,e,f
g
h
x,y,z
```

Add an END block to your AWK:

```
  END {
    if (d[1] != "") print d[1]
    if (d[0] != "") print d[0]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me how to generalize your question.  (ie, what do you want to do with an 8 line file?), but for the particular case in which you seem to want to swap the 2nd and 3rd lines and paste, you could use:

```
perl -e 'chomp (my @ar =<>); @ar[1,2] = @ar[2, 1]; map { $_ .= ($i++%2 ? "\n" : ",")} @ar; print @ar' input
```

Perhaps you can modify that to suit your needs.